# 2001 Audi A4 corroded part... What is it?

Tags: engine, part-identification, audi

I noticed under my hood that a piece looks corroded through.  My car hasn't given any warnings or check engine lights and no liquid is coming through.  No one I ask knows what it is. Please help!

https://plus.google.com/101255102843039720628/posts

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a check valve for the evaporative emissions system. Hard plastic tubing and the solenoid valve on the left side are strong clues for me.

Comment: I believe you're right. Doing a google search for check valve I found this which looks very similar. Thanks!  http://www.vorwerkauto.com/audi/a4/1996-2001-b5/used-vacuum-check-valve-96-08-audi-a4-a6-058-905-291.html